# Proof for a hypothetical postulated

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, decimal-expansion

I wish to know, if it is possible to prove the following facts using any known facts (till elementary school level):

Only **1** and **9** are the perfect odd numbered squares which are *entirely* made up of odd numbers / digits.

There are **NO** other such perfect squares.

That means, if you take any other **odd numbered** square it would at least containg one even-numbered digit. For example: 25 / 49 / 81 etc.

Any clues / hints towards proof are also welcome !

Comment: I think that [this link](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55902.html) answers your question, which is from Dr Math.

Comment: @TobyMak Make it an answer!

Comment: See [**this**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2398670/why-are-the-last-two-digits-of-a-perfect-square-never-both-odd/2399140#2399140) for example.

Answer (score 1):

*This proof is adapted from a question from [Dr Math](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55902.html).*

Notice that the last two digits of $\color{red}{1^2}$ and $\color{blue}{99^2}$ ; $\color{red}{3^2}$ and $\color{blue}{97^2}$, $\color{red}{5^2}$ and $\color{blue}{95^2}$ and so on, are exactly the same. We can prove this using algebra; looking at the numbers $x^2$ and $x^2-200x+10000$, we see that only the **$100$s place** and **$10000$s place** are changed in the second number, but not the $1$s or the $10$s place.

We can do the exact same thing with $\color{red}{1^2}$ and $\color{blue}{49^2}$ ; $\color{red}{3^2}$ and $\color{blue}{47^2}$, $\color{red}{5^2}$ and $\color{blue}{45^2}$. With the two numbers $x^2$ and $x^2-100x+2500$, we can again see that the last two digits are not changed in the second number.

Now check the squares of the numbers from $1$ to $25$, and see which ones have an even digit. Since adding any multiple of $100$ to $x$ (shown by expanding $(x+100k)^2 = x^2+200xk+10000k^2)$ to these numbers will not affect the last two digits, your conclusion about these numbers holds regardless of the number's **$100$s**, **$1000$s**, **$10000$s** or higher places.

Comment: Well, thanks @Toby Mak, for the link and an explanation. Is the shared proof of a type -'induction' ? Or any other specific types  it falls into ? Please clarify

Comment: I would classify this type as casework - you would need to check the cases of $1^2$, $3^2$, $5^2$ etc. and see if that number has any even digits. Induction is a totally different type of proof.